# Is it possible to use google analytics for server side?

Tags: statistics, google-analytics, server-side

Is it possible to use google analytics for server side? We are quite familiar with using google analytics for client side of things, but we found ourselves needing to keep track of server events as well. Where should we go for this? Ideally we want to make simple calls and it can help us track sessions length, frequencies, trends etc

I'm not looking for software that analysis and parse my log files. The apache log files is not sufficient, we need to know specific events inside each page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Code contains this tool (if you're using PHP 5.2+):

http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/

Other than that, there was a similar question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287260/are-there-any-free-and-open-source-server-side-analytics-engines

Comment: "Google" didn't release this. It's just hosted on Google Code. It was created by independent developers.

Comment: Is there some reasonable degree of certainty that it won't up and disappear one day, with no warning? I see that it's hosted on google, so, I'm hoping I can read into that fact the assumption that it's a library I can depend on?

Answer (score 0):

This project looks good too: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/